# routerLink with outlet redirects to 404 error page

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, router-outlet

I have a angular 4 application and I am not able to set a working `routerLink` for navigation. The request gets always redirected to my 404 error page.

Here is my code:

The relevant part of my **route-config** in my `NgModule`:

```
{
   path: 'Transactions',
   component: TransactionIndexComponent,
   children: [
      {
         path: 'Add',
         outlet: "next",
         component: TransactionAddComponent,
         children: [
            { path: "AddPerson", component: PersonsAddComponent, outlet: "next" }
         ]
      },
   ]
},
```

The relevant part of `TransactionsIndexComponent` template:

```
<a routerLink="[{ outlets: { next: 'Add' } } ]" class="tile">Add</a>

<router-outlet name="next"></router-outlet>
```

The relevant part of `TransactionAddComponent` template:

```
<a routerLink="[{ outlets: { next: 'AddPerson' } } ]" class="tile">Add Person</a>

<router-outlet name="next"></router-outlet>
```

I tried these values for `routerLink` in `TransactionsIndexComponent`:

1. `['', { outlets: { next: 'Add' } } ]`
2. `[{ outlets: { next: 'Add' } }]`

None of them worked. **What is the problem?**

PS: The templates it self with the nested `router-outlet`s are working, because I can open an address like `/Transactions/(next:Add/(next:AddPerson))` without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I missed the square brackets in `[routerLink]`. This works well:

```
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { next: 'Add' } } ]" class="tile">Add</a>

<router-outlet name="next"></router-outlet>
```